# Why does there hold $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = f'(b) - \int_a^b \frac{x-a}{b-a} f''(x) dx$ for a smooth $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I find a basic formula in a lecture note that I never saw before: 
$$
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = f'(b) - \int_a^b \frac{x-a}{b-a} f''(x) dx
$$
for a smooth real-valued function $f(x)$ and $b>a$.

It looks like some fundamental corollary derived from the mean value theorem or Taylor expansion. Anyone let me know what the name of the formula is, and how we may prove it?

Comment: The integral can be simplified by integrating by parts

Comment: @clark I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating by parts we get $\int_a^{b} \frac  {x-a} {b-a} f''(x) dx=\frac  {x-a} {b-a} f'(x)|_a^{b} -\frac  1 {b-a} \int _a^{b} f'(x)dx$. Can you proceed?

Comment: Yes, I can. Thank you very much! By the way, any name of the original formula?